# using _wspawnl to spawn a proce

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm building a Windows x64 bit application in Visual Studios and trying to use _wspawnl to spawn a process.  There are a few examples on Stack Overflow, but none that address my problem.  I can execute the command from a Windows Command window successfully:

`D:\arinc629\executable\load_config eelab_rgcu_atp.cfg`.

After this command is executed, I can see the process "load_config" running in the Windows Task Manager.

This code compiles and executes, but I get a non-zero number for `loadHandle`, which indicates a abnormal exit in the Microsoft documentation.

```
int loadHandle = 0;
const wchar_t *app = L"d:\\arinc629\\executable\\load_config.exe";
const wchar_t *argv = L"d:\\arinc629\\executable\\eelab_rgcu_atp.cfg";
loadHandle = _wspawnl(_P_WAIT, app, argv, NULL);
```

Not sure why it's not working.

Comment: You're missing the `arg0` which is normally the executable name. Try `_wspawnl(_P_WAIT, app, app, argv, NULL)`

Comment: RustyX, that was it.  I didn't recognize that in the documentation.  thanks.